# Why is the Span of a subset of a linear space defined in such at way?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

If I have a subset $M$ of a linear space $E$, we define the linear span of the subset, $M$, as:

$$\operatorname{span} M=\bigcap_\alpha \{E_\alpha : E_\alpha \hookrightarrow E\text{ and } M \subseteq E_\alpha\}$$

I.e. the intersection of all spaces containing $M$.

---

The subset will be vectors correct? Hence we could just take all elements that are scalar multiples of our elements right? Why this definition?

Comment: probably good to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to define the span of $M$, what you wrote in your first paragraph is one of them.

Taking all scalar multiples of elements of $M$ does **not** give the correct definition of the span of $M$: in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the set of all scalar multiples of $M=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ is the union of the $x$-axis with the $y$-axis which is not even a subspace.

But there is another useful way to define the span of $M$, namely, the set of all linear combinations of the form $a_1 u_1 + \cdots + a_k u_k$ where $k$ varies over the natural numbers, $u_1,\ldots,u_k$ vary over $M$, and $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ vary over the scalar field. This definition is equivalent to the one you give in your first paragraph.

Comment: Oh sorry yes, I just lazily wrote that scalar multiple part, I did indeed mean the linear combinations.

Seeing as they are equivalent, is there some benefit to the definition I have posted? Is it to cover the case where we are in an infinite dimensional space, and hence we can't take linear combinations of our infinite vectors?

Comment: Its elegance makes it easy to apply in some proofs.

Comment: Can the linear combination definition be worked for infinite dimensional spaces?

Comment: Infinite linear combinations are not allowed in the ordinary definition of span. They do come up in some situations, though, e.g. in Hilbert spaces, Fourier analysis, etc.